# How do I make a query for people that like everybody they know using `NOT EXISTS`?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to select for the following tables people who likes everybody they know, and I must use NOT EXISTS

```
Persons{id, name}
Knows {personA_id, personB_id}
Likes {PersonA_id, PersonB_id}
```

The syntax of the tables `Knows` and `Likes` is
`PersonA likes/knows personB`, where `personA_id` and `personB_id` refer to the id of a person from the table `Persons`.

I have tried to solve it like this:

```
SELECT p1.id, p2.name
FROM Persons p1, Persons p2, Knows k
WHERE k.personA_id = p1.id AND k.personB_id = p2.id
AND NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM Likes l
   WHERE l.personA_id <> p1.id AND l.PersonB_id = p2.id
)
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: `JOIN`. `JOIN`. `JOIN`.

Comment: Where does the NOT EXISTS requirement come from?

Comment: how does any of these answers, answer the question ?
this can defenatly be solved without any join

Comment: Add some data and show the wnated result for starters,. but what you basically doing is a cross join and produce every possible combination and then try to reduces again. which doesn't make any sense so do it with joins and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down

First let's get a list of everyone a person knows

```
select * from knows k
```

Now let's take the list of the people they know and see who they like

```
select * from knows k
left join likes l on k.persona_id = l.persona_id and k.personb_id = l.personb_i
```

In this list, you will have everyone they know (k.personb_id).  If they like them, l.personb_id will match k.personb_id. If not, l.personb_id will be null.

So now we want to get a list of everyone who likes everyone they know, in other words, there are no nulls in the l.personb_id field of the above query

```
Select * from persons p
where not exists(
select * from knows k
left join likes l on k.persona_id = l.persona_id and k.personb_id = l.personb_id
where k.persona_id = p.id and l.personb_id is null
)
```

Try it here on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=7a3b36fc162efe3431839660f116943f)